# Linux - 2 VMs - one acess to internet

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, routing

I am currently learning about Linux routing.
I am running CentOS 7.

I would like to acess internet from VM which has internal network adapter and use second VM which has both internal network adapter and NAT adapter as gateway.

How should I setup routes in such case?

#### VM1

- VM

  ```
  enp0s3 - inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0 - NAT
  enp0s8 - inet 198.162.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0 - internal network
  ```
- ROUTES

  ```
  default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100
  10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
  198.162.0.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 198.162.0.1 metric 100
  ```

---

#### VM2

- VM only internal network

  ```
  inet 198.162.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 - internal network
  ```
- ROUTES:
  destination 198.162.0.0 gateway. 0.0.0.0;

> ping from VM1 to VM2 is working; ping from VM1 to 8.8.8.8 (outside world) is working as well;
>
> I am not able to add default gateway via 198.162.0.1, it always shows me an error (Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "gw" is garbage)
>
> It also occured me whether it is possible to does it this way, since it is only internal network

Answer (score 0):

Looks good so far, but the 2. VM (only internal network) also needs a `192.168.0.0/24` route (which normally gets added automatically when you add the IP address) and a default route `default via 192.168.0.1/24` to the 1. VM (nearly always gets added automatically). Otherwise the 2. VM won't know where to send packets destined for "the internet".

Troubleshooting:

Use `ping` to see if the VM's can communicate with each other, if the 1. VM can communicate with the internet (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8` to the Google DNS server), and finally if the 2. VM can communicate with the internet (via the 1. VM).

Use `ip route get <ip_addr>` to verify if your idea how routes are resolved matches the routing tables.

Comment: It did not help. Is it even possible? I mean there is only internal network apapter on it.